# Webpack configuration in Gatsby, naming conventions

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby in one of my projects, and due to its configs, in the server side, Node doesn't have the `window` loader. All that being said I found the guides in Gatsby docs for a previous package on how to avoid having these errors:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html' || stage === 'develop-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /enter-package-name/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
};
```

Recently I've encountered the same error, and in part fault due to my lack of knowledge of Webpack and its naming conventions that are used, I couldn't use the same configuration for this package:

```
rules: [
    {
       test: /@brainhubeu/react-carousel/
    }
]
```

I believe the slashes are used to locate the package, and due to the naming of my package having one in between the two words, its throwing an error due to not expecting something after the middle slash.

Any ideas on how I would do this either regex wise or Webpack. Materials and docs about said issue are welcomed.

P.S - Apologies if this question might be very basic, but I couldn't find the proper documentation on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit the nail. As you guess, `test` is a regular expression (hence the slashes, `/`) and it tests a folder location inside `node_modules`. In your case, you may need to scape the middle slash with something like:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-html' || stage === 'develop-html') {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /@brainhubeu\/react-carousel/,
            use: loaders.null(),
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Technically the solution you provided `did work`, however the way it worked is that it prompted other errors elsewhere outside the scope of the package. 

Basically the build-html was then affected as a result of it. 
In the end I opted for react-slick, since the package above is 'only' supported in Next.js and not Gatsby. 

Accepting the answer as It might help others with the issue of naming convention. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you, who run into the same issue on Windows - remember that it uses backslash for file paths. So what you should do is add an additional test:

```
test: /@brainhubeu\\react-carousel/
```